# jQuery .html() function doesnt work in IE 11

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-11

In my .net MVC3 web application i have an ajax call that returns some html code. I pass this html into a div like so:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'controller/action',
            data: {id: id,},
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#container").html(data);

            },
        });
```

This works fine in all browsers except ie 11. What happens is that the html doesnt render in #container div unless i click somewhere on the page.

How can i get the html to render without clicking anywhere in ie11?

thanks

Comment: have you set the container height width ? I think there might be issue that rendering does not taken place due to this.

Comment: I have not. but i tried setting a height and width and it still didnt work.

Comment: try console for errors and check for unclosed tags. Your html should be clean. and if still doesnot work try `$('div').append(data);` OR `$('div').appendTo(data);`

Comment: Whats even more odd is that it works fine in ie9.

Comment: A browser-specific bug. Report it to jQuery, and they'll patch it. - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues

Comment: try using  document.body.innerHTML="<h1>Hello World</h1>";  i am not sure whether it work on IE11 or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely cause for this is that there is some small piece of syntax in the HTML that is returned by ajax that IE is not happy with. In my case it was caused by having an HTML comment inside a `<script>` tag. IE fell over but other browsers were fine.

I suggest removing everything from the HTML returned by the ajax call except one line such as 'TEST'. If that works then you know it isn't a JQuery / Javascript issue. You can then add back lines into the returned HTML until you find the line that IE isn't happy with.

Comment: The bug no longer appears to be an issue with my clients. Im not sure exactly why... it may have been a browser bug but in any case, i accept your answer because i agree with your method of debugging. It has worked wonders in the past

Answer (score 3):

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'controller/action',
            data: {id: id,},
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
$("#container").empty().append(data);


            },
        });
```

Use append instead of html to avoid those issues. empty() is used to clear intially before append.

Comment: To avoid which issues exactly?