# Internet Explorer renders entire view within a partial update

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- jQuery 1.11.3

Apologies for the long post, but I really need a nudge in the right direction as I just cannot see what the issue is here.

The following works perfectly for Chrome, Firefox but IE it doesn't.

The CORRECT result will look something like this:

[image]

However in IE 11 the WRONG result is as follows:

[image]

Under the skin there is some JavaScript doing the updating with some AJAX callbacks to an MVC Controller:

```
//Applies the selected filter from the values selected in the drop down
function ApplyFilter() {
    var brandSelected = $('#filterBrand').val();
    var cruiseLengthSelected = $('#filterCruiseLength').val();
    var departureDateSelected = $('#filterDepartureDate').val();
    var departureFromSelected = $('#filterDepartFrom').val();
    var regionSelected = $('#filterRegion').val();
    var shipSelected = $('#filterShip').val();

    cruisesTemplate.UiBlock('.entire-page');
    cruisesTemplate.UiSetBusy('.entire-page');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/cruises/currentcruiselistfilterset?' +
            'aBrandId=' +
            brandSelected +
            '&aCruiseLength=' +
            cruiseLengthSelected +
            '&aDepartureDate=' +
            departureDateSelected.replace(' ', '_') +
            '&aRegionHierarchyItemId=' +
            regionSelected +
            '&aDepartureFromHierarchyItemId=' +
            departureFromSelected +
            '&aShipId=' +
            shipSelected
    })
        .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
            cruisesTemplate.UiClearBlock('.entire-page');
            cruisesTemplate.UiClearBusy('.entire-page');
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'GET',
                url: window.location.href
            })
                .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
                    cruisesTemplate.UiClearBlock('.entire-page');
                    cruisesTemplate.UiClearBusy('.entire-page');
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);

                    //Now refresh the filter bar
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'html',
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/cruises/filterbarrefresh'
                    })
                        .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
                            cruisesTemplate.UiClearBlock('.entire-page');
                            cruisesTemplate.UiClearBusy('.entire-page');
                        })
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $('#filter-bar').html(data);
                            cruisesTemplate.UiClearBlock('.entire-page');
                            cruisesTemplate.UiClearBusy('.entire-page');
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that this is either a timing issue (unlikely) or perhaps a timing issue in conjunction with the **url: window.location.href** (more likely) that is causing the issue.

**EDIT:**
It appears that definitively **url: window.location.href** is the issue as in the browsers this works in I see the following AJAX requests:

> https://localhost/cruises/filterbarrefresh
>   https://localhost/departing/australia/cruises
>   https://localhost/cruises/currentcruiselistfilterset?abrandid=8&acruiselength=0&adeparturedate=january_2015&aregionhierarchyitemid=1&adeparturefromhierarchyitemid=73&ashipid=0

whereas in IE I see only this AJAX request (and hence the full site updated within the update area as it us doing a full page request:

https://localhost/departing/australia/cruises

I have also verified that this is not a jQuery.html() issue as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362015/jquery-html-function-doesnt-work-in-ie-11). Using dummy hard coded strings or the $("#container").empty().append(data); pattern still results in the same IE bad behaviour.

**/EDIT:**

My fundamental question(s) are:

- How can I make this work in IE (and Chrome, Firefox etc.) without changing the existing JS logic?
- Have I missed something fundamental in terms of jQuery, Promises etc. in terms of how this is implemented that is bad practice?

All pointers and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `window.location.href` rather than `@Url.Action()`? And generating your url the way you are doing in the first call is bad practice. You should also be using `url: @Url.Action("currentcruiselistfilterset", "cruises"),` and sending the parameters using `data: { aBrandId: brandSelected, aCruiseLength: cruiseLengthSelected, etc }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Understood and agreed re bad practice and I will review and update my code locally. However irrespective that will make no difference to the fact that IE is doing something totally different to the other browsers. Any idea why IE is doing what it is doing?

Comment: Are you surprised something is working differently in IE :). But what do you have those chained ajax calls anyway. The first one is calling the `currentcruiselistfilterset()` and you get back some data (not sure if its html or json) but you never do anything with that data (its just thrown away). Then in the success callback you make another ajax call to the url returned by `location.href` (which is the url of the current page) to update the DOM.

Comment: In fact what is the purpose of the 3rd ajax call. Why are you updating the filter bar? Looking at the site, all its doing is updating it with exactly what it was before

Comment: The 3rd call is to make the filterbar reflect the current selection as it is out of wack with what is displayed.

Comment: No not surprised it does not work in IE ;-) However with all this talk about IE being "great" and compliant once again, you can always but hope. And then be sadly disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here ended up being turning OFF caching for the jQuery AJAX calls so:

$.ajax({cache: false;});